# hosts file and unclear behavior. How to make real alias?

Tags: command-line, webserver, nginx, hosts, vagrant

I'm trying to create alias for my local website which is runned by vagrant(virtual box), hence I want redirect any requests from site.ru to 192.168.10.10/site.ru via `/etc/hosts` file. In the hosts file I have the following:

```
...
192.168.10.10/site.ru    site.ru
```

However it doesn't work as I want. When I go to site.ru I'm appear in the 'real' site. I hope anybody understand me to answer for my question..

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Solution: [How to setup mass dynamic virtual hosts in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464835/1349754)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely direct a host name to an IP address on your LAN with Ubuntu's `hosts` file, but it does not support the particular syntax you're using. From [`man hosts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/hosts.5.html):

> This file is a simple text file that associates IP addresses with
>   hostnames, one line per IP address. For each host a single line should
>   be present with the following information:
>
> ```
> IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
> ```

The hosts file in Ubuntu does not direct hostnames with *other hostnames*, but only with IP addresses.

Therefore, instead of writing:

```
192.168.10.10/site.ru    site.ru
```

You should instead write:

```
192.168.10.10            site.ru
```

This will cause `site.ru` to be resolved to `192.168.10.10` instead of whatever it would otherwise be resolved to via DNS.

*However*, this may or may not effectively direct all traffic that is (conceptually) associated with the `site.ru` domain name. In particular, it will typically not be sufficient to cause a domain like `www.site.ru` to be mapped to 192.168.10.10 as well. To achieve that, add `www.site.ru` explicitly:

```
192.168.10.10            site.ru   www.site.ru
```

(You can alternatively make a separate line for it, if you prefer. This line must also start with an IP address.)

#### But `hosts` will not direct traffic to a specific folder on a website.

If by `192.168.10.10/site.ru` you mean the `site.ru` directory on the web server at `192.168.10.10` (that is, if you are using `/` as a *[path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) separator*), you cannot use the `hosts` file to do this. `hosts` files do not facilitate that behavior on *any* operating system; it is fundamentally unrelated to what `hosts` files do.

The reason this cannot work is that hosts files redirect host names to IP addresses. But `192.168.10.10/site.ru` is not an IP address. It's an IP address followed by *directory retrieval information sent to the IP address through an [application-layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) protocol*. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) on the meaning of different parts of a URL (and how only one part is resolved via IP).

The proper solution in this sort of situation is to configure the *web server* to serve different content depending on which host name is used to access the site. This can work because the HTTP protocol includes the ability of web browsers to tell the web server what host name it is using (and essentially all web browsers send this information whenever it's applicable).

If you have the ability to make changes to the web server and need help setting up ["virtual hosts,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) and the web server is an Ubuntu system, please feel free to post a separate question about that here.

If you don't have the ability to make changes to the web server, you should talk to whoever does.

If even *that* is absolutely not an option, then you should edit your question (or post a new one, your choice) to clarify your situation in detail. A messier workaround that fits your needs *might* be possible. It would probably involve an HTTP [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) running on each *client* machine and redirecting HTTP traffic by URL.

Comment: You offer me the solution that doesn't fit to my situation. I need to redirect exactly `192.168.10.10/site.ru` to `site.ru`, because root of `192.168.10.10` just contains 2 folders: site.ru site2.ru andnothing more. If I connect to the root I get nothinng as well..What can I do in my situation?

Comment: I did not realize that you were using `/` as a directory separator. Unfortunately you cannot do this with a `hosts` file. I have expanded my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

That is the right syntax `IP ADDRESS SITE.COM` real example`127.0.0.134 hackme.org`